# Can't edit products after update to 2.1.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I updated **Magento to 2.1.4**.

Now, there are **extension dependency issues** when I tried to update the extensions. The more important issue is that I can't edit any products. The products are still on the front end of my website. They are also still displayed on the product grid on the back end, however, when I click them to edit, I get a black page with the product name on it. See the photo below:
[image: Product with no edit fields]

I get the same black screen for blocks and CMS pages.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like this is a 2.1.4 bug as you're not the only one in this case: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/158800/2380

Comment: Is there errors in browser console or in magento logs (var/log folder)?

Comment: I have upgraded to 2.1.4 CE i don't have any issues. It works fine. Please check log

Comment: open the website in private window(incognito mode) and check it is works !!! you need to delete browser cache and cookies manually

Comment: It's really weird. I deleted some old backups on the server, and it worked. I'm not sure if that makes any sense, but I ended making a new backup after that and we're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete cache and then try.
2. if not then please run setup upgrade and static file deploy command.